# How to install Epson L350 scan driver on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, scanner, epson

I cannot install normally scan drivers for my scanner. I downloaded drivers for ubuntu (32bits) (http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html) but I don't know what to write in terminal.

On this web-site and others I found just "how to install epson drivers for 16.04" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb.tar.gz` to your Home directory and run

```
tar -xvzf iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb.tar.gz
tar -xvzf iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb
after all these in terminal is wrotten error or command is not found
after this sudo ./install.sh terminal wants my password, but i cant write the password....why???

Comment: the problem is that i can`t write the password in home directory

Comment: What do you mean by "can't write password"? The password is not displayed. Type it and press Enter.